# The confusing ls command: "ls -t" versus "ls -u"

Tags: ls

In Unix `ls -l` gives us a long listing of files and directories.
`ls -lt` additionally *sorts* the files by time, i.e. last changed or modified. This is to be distinguished from,
`ls -lu` which gives the long listing and the access time and sorts the files from a-z, not by last access.
I would expect `ls -lu` to sort files by access time, but for this I need:
`ls -lut` which gives the listing in long format, prints the access time, and sorts by access time.

ERGO,
`-t` must mean sort by time, either modified or access time, whereas,
`-u` means only *list* access time. It does not mean list and sort by access time.
Without any further argument then, `-t` seems to mean list by modified time *and sort* by modified time.
Is the above correct. If not, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you check the explanation for `-t` and `-u` in `info ls` or [online](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Sorting-the-output.html#Sorting-the-output)?

Comment: What Unix are you on? `ls -u` on GNU systems is the same as `ls -ut` on any other Unix.

Comment: I am using GNU Linux - Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mostly correct, `-t` means "sort by time" and `-u` means "use the atime timestamp" (when sorting with `-t` or when showing the timestamp with `-l`).  The POSIX `-u` option does not imply changing the default order of sorting unless `-t` is also used to explicitly request sorting by a timestamp.

[The POSIX specification of `ls`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) has the following bits of text in it:

> `-u`
>
> Use time of last access (see XBD <sys/stat.h>) instead of last modification of the file for sorting (`-t`) or writing (`-l`).

However, the GNU people thought that it would be convenient to let `ls -u` also *sort* by atime, since otherwise there would be no difference between the outputs of `ls -u` and `ls` (both would be sorted by name and no timestamps would show).  This is why GNU `ls` works differently from any other system's implementation of `ls`.

The documentation of `ls` on a GNU system summarizes this as

> `-u`
>
> with `-lt`: sort by, and show, access time; with `-l`: show access
> time and sort by name; otherwise: sort by access time, newest
> first

What's not mentioned in this short text is that any other options that provides a *similar* output format as `-l`, e.g. `-o`, `-g` and `-n`, also removes the sorting effect from the `-u` option like `-l` does.  These options all have the text "like `-l` but, ..." in the GNU `ls` manual.

The `-c` option in GNU `ls` depends on other options in a similar way to sort/display the ctime timestamp.

The GNU `ls` has worked like this [since 1999](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/4d90b0efc94a22ec501f4324dcc6ddd26100b8d2) or thereabouts.

Regardless of what implementation of `ls` you are using, to sort the  long format output on a timestamp, you will have to use `-t`. Use `-l -ut` to sort on atime, `-l -ct` to sort on ctime, or just `-l -t` to sort on mtime.

Comment: That documentation seems to be inaccurate (regarding “otherwise”):  things like `ls -ou` and `ls -gu` also sort by name.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' So it seems, but I think the main point is that `-u` would sort by atime in combination with _any_ option that gave you a long listing format, but only if combined with `-t`.

Comment: But that's not what it says.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' See also added text about `-g`, `-o` and `-n`

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', yeah, the short description is inexact, or they're thinking the case with no other options when they say "otherwise". `-u` without `-t` also doesn't override other sort specifiers (like the `-v` I had on by default). Though I would say it does say that `ls -ou` doesn't sort by atime, exactly because `-o` specifically says it's "similar to `-l`" and `-u` with `-l` doesn't affect sorting, only display.

Comment: @devcom, I'm not having a formal discourse here. If you think there's a problem with my comments (e.g. being unfriendly, unkind or containing harassment or abuse), flag them for moderators.

Answer (score 2):

The [`ls` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) can help clarify these options.

The `-l` option controls output format, producing a 'long' listing.

The `-t` option sorts by modification time. This value is already present in the long format.

The `-u` option behaves differently based on the options it is used with.

1. On its own, as `ls -u`, it sorts by access time.
2. With the `-l` option, it displays the access time, but sorts by name. In this case, it acts as an output modifier rather than a sorting option.
3. With `-l` and `-t`, it shows the access time and also sorts by it.

The `-c` option works the same way with the ctime property.

The complexity comes from the need to modify the long listing format. Several other options work this way: `-lo` to suppress group information, `-lG` to suppress owner information, `-lh` to display sizes in human-readable format, and so on).

---

The GNU-style options from the [`ls` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html#ls-invocation) makes this easier to understand.

`-l` is `--format=long`.

`-t` is `--sort=time`.

`-u` is `--time=atime`.

So `-lu` is `--format=long --time=atime`. That is, show the long listing, but with atime instead of the default mtime.

And `-ltu` is `--format=long --sort=time --time=atime`. In this case, show the atime and sort by it.

Comment: That thing with `ls -u` actually sorting differently than `ls` seems to be a GNU thing. No other `ls` that I have access to does that (e.g. macOS, or any of the BSDs, or Plan 9). `ls -u` will sort on the name, and `ls -ut` will sort on the atime.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, because I don’t recall noticing it before. To clarify: in GNU, `ls -u` sorts by access time, but `ls -lu` sorts by name.

Comment: I think @Kusalananda has hit upon the cause of the confusion. ls -u should not exist as it does in GNU because it implies that u has sorting capabilities which it does not. u simply specifies the time to be sorted as atime (when used with t) or the time to be displayed (when used with l).

Comment: @devcom, eh, what should not happen is people using random options to a utility without checking what they mean. The GNU manpage does mention `-u` affecting sorting too, if `-l` is not given.  If you don't want that, don't use it. It's a not a huge loss, since by the POSIX description `-u` without `-t` should be meaningless anyway, so there's no reason to use it.

Comment: I must disagree. I did consult the man page and unfortunately it fails to lay out clearly there what has been answered clearly in this post. Many people use commands they do not fully understand as a way of understanding how those commands work. My point is that GNU sometimes implements UNIX commands in a way that is less satisfactory than the original.

Comment: I believe that the point that some people are trying to make is that the GNU developers should not have introduced a *subtle* non-conformity to POSIX without clearly identifying it as such. Compare to the `gawk` documentation, where (1) there are large, obvious differences from POSIX `awk`, ***and*** (2) there are repeated explicit statements about how `gawk` behavior differs from POSIX `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

`-t` means *sort* by time — some time field.

`-u` means work with access time instead of modification time
(for display **and/or** sorting, as applicable).

So you understand it correctly;
you’re just confusing yourself by making it more complicated than it is. 
Take a step back and take a deep breath,
and you’ll see it’s not so complicated.

P.S. Note that `-t` ***without `-l`***
(or a similar option, like `-o` or `-g`)
will not *display* any time field.

Comment: Taking a step back did help thanks.